# Example of a function whose second derivative does not exist but limiting formula for the second derivative holds

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Here's Exercise 11 in Baby Rudin:

> Suppose $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of $x$, and suppose $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ exists. Show that
> \begin{equation}\label{11.0}
>     \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)+ f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2} = f^{\prime\prime}(x)
> \end{equation}
> Show by an example that the limit may exist even if $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ does not.

I had no trouble proving the statement but I am having trouble coming up with an example. Initially, I thought of:

$f(x) =
      \begin{cases}
      x+1 & \text{if $x<0$} \\
      0 & \text{if $x=0$} \\
      x-1& \text{if $x>0$}
      \end{cases}
    $

Then, as $h \to 0$,
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)+ f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2} =
  \begin{cases}
  \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h+1)+ (x-h+1)-2x-2}{h^2} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h^2}=0 & \text{if $x<0$} \\
  \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h^2}=0 & \text{if $x=0$} \\
  \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h-1)+ (x-h-1)-2x+2}{h^2} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h^2}=0& \text{if $x>0$}
  \end{cases}$

Note that $f(0-) = f(0+) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} f(0) = 0$. However, this also leads me to:

$f''(x) =
  \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if $x<0$} \\
  0 & \text{if $x=0$} \\
  0& \text{if $x>0$}
  \end{cases}$

**Is my example even correct at all? If not, can someone suggest a better example and show how $f''(x)$ does not exist (presumably at some point)?**

Comment: The example is correct though not the explanation. Observe that $\;f'(0)\;$ doesn't exist ($\;f\;$ isn't even continuous at zero ) and thus obviously neither does $\;f''(0)\;$

Comment: How about $x^3/|x|$ ?

Comment: Can you convince yourself that "however this _does not_ lead me to" the result about $f''(x) $ for $x=0$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, I can now, after the comments and the answer. I think where I went wrong was that I was supposed to first check whether $f$ is continuous at $x=0$. Since $f$ is not continuous $x=0$, it is clear that $f$ cannot be differentiable even once at $x=0$.

Comment: In general when a function is defined by different formulas on different domains, it is always necessary to check continuity, differentiability etc, on the boundary of different domains using definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about $f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
       -x^2 & \text{if $x<0$} \\
        x^2 & \text{if $x\geq 0$} \\
\end{cases}
$.

second derivative at $0$ does not exist
but the limit zero

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)+ f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2}$$
at $x=0$ exists (and is equal to $0$).

Comment: it's basically the same answer as @JonathanZ supports MonicaC gave in the comments. I hadn't checked the comments. I cannot delete an accepted answer!

Comment: It's all good. You did a thorough write up that I couldn't be bothered to do. Have an upvote.